# EditText clicking disables footer elements clicking

Tags: android, button, focus, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I have ListView with the header and footer. Header - is a long ScrollView with set of EditTexts and Spinners. There're two buttons in the footer. When I click at one of the EditText, and after that click on the footer's button it doesn't fire. When I click at some another header's element, I see the result of footer's button handler. When I do not click on this EditText, footer's button works properly. My EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/orderTitle"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/levelSpin"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Order title(specify)"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
```

I think the problem that editText clicking disfocus the footer View. So I tried to make like this in my button's setOnClickListener:

```
btnSubmitOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        footer.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        deadline.setFocusable(false);
        orderTitle.setFocusable(false);
        header.clearFocus();
        btnSubmitOrder.setFocusable(true);
        Log.i("new order button","fires");
        boolean errorFlag = false;
    }
});
```

But it doesn't help. I also tried to like this:

```
orderTitle.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            orderTitle.setFocusable(false);
            Log.i("onEditorAction","yeah");
        }
        Log.i("onEditorAction","yeah");
        return false;
    }
});
```

do disfocus this EditText when the user's actions were finished, but it also didn't help. How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved issue by using

```
btnSubmitOrder.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        {
                     header.clearFocus();
                        }
                   }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

There another alternative and its to set the following on the footer.  There is another method overload created but it did not come up in the docs(at least in my IDE it didn't), i had to check online documentation:

```
mylistView.addFooterView(footerView, null, **false**);
```

where false tells the footer its not selectable.  I tested this myself and the buttons inside the footer respond to touches.  I hope this an acceptable answer.

otherwise as you mentioned you'll have to use a ontouchlistener as the listview and button are fighting for focus and listview is winning. Thats why when you clicked on the listview the button was not firing anymore, as the listview got the focus.